# how to apply delay in displaying ng-repeat elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm new to angularjs and want to apply a delay of 500ms to every ng-repeat element.The code in the plunker below is the exact thing i am looking for but it does not work with latest version of angular js (1.4.8).The following website also describes how to apply delay but it's a bit confusing which says about add-active and -remove.

here is the html,css and angular code

```
<script>
  var m = angular.module('App', []);

  m.controller('ExampleCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.items = [];

        $scope.addItems = function() {
          $scope.items = [
          {name: "Apple"},
          {name: "Orange"},
          {name: "Banana"},
          {name: "Lemon"},
          {name: "Lime"},
          {name: "Melon"},
          {name: "Tangerine"}
          ];
        }
  });

</script>
```

```
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      position:relative;
    }

    li {
      background-color:#e3e3e3;
      color: #666;
      font-family:Arial;
      padding:1em;
      margin:0 5px 5px 5px;
      text-align: center;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .insert-enter {
      -webkit-transform:scale(0);
      -webkit-transition-property: all;
      -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out-cubic;
      -webkit-transition-duration: 400ms;
    }
    .insert-enter.insert-enter-active {
      -webkit-transform:scale(1);
    }

</style>
```

```
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items" 
          ng-animate="{enter:'insert-enter'}"
          style="-webkit-transition-delay:{{$index * 500}}ms"
      > 
            {{item.name}}
      </li> 
    </ul>
```

[Punker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/D46PSH?p=preview)

[website about ng-repeat classes](https://css-tricks.com/animations-the-angular-way/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working demo of your code https://plnkr.co/edit/LR9yadLEQySdQjTr6jg5?p=preview

Things I've changed:

- Included the `ngAnimate` module `var m = angular.module('App', ['ngAnimate']);`
- Added a button in your HTML code `<button ng-click="addItems()">Add Items</button>`
- Included the angular animate library in your HTML `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular-animate.js`
- Removed `ng-animate="{enter:'insert-enter'}"`
- Renamed `.insert-enter` to `.ng-enter`
- Renamed `.insert-enter.insert-enter-active` to `.ng-enter.ng-enter-active`

Comment: ThankYou for your help and saving my time :)

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to include ngAnimate dependency in your angular module, and also include ngAnimate library in your index.html file

Comment: i added the dependency and library to the code but still it does not work.